Tensorflow GEMM launch failures
I'm rnning a GNN model using virtual environment.My GPU is RTX 4050,
my max CUDA driver version shown on setting is 12.3
so I choose my tensorflow version 2.0.0 according to a blog with CUDA 10.0.130/cuDNN7.6.5  
the tool  I use to  install is conda
conda create -n tensorflow2.0.0 python=3.8
conda activate tensorflow2.0.0
conda install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=10.0.130 cudnn=7.6.5

and in test it turns out the GPU is available

but when I'm running the model ,the erro shows below
2024-07-23 14:06:06.254986: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:428] failed to run cuBLAS routine: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow2.00\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1365, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow2.00\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _run_fn
    target_list, run_metadata)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow2.00\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1443, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(4, 256), b.shape=(4, 256), m=256, n=256, k=4
     [[{{node gradients/MatMul_1_grad/MatMul_1}}]]

with some other error
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(4, 256), b.shape=(4, 256), m=256, n=256, k=4
     [[node gradients/MatMul_1_grad/MatMul_1 (defined at Anaconda\envs\tensorflow2.00\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]]

I search on line and find some encounter this when their batch_size is too large for display memory but even  change it to 4 it still don't work,can anyone give me a clue?

